# Removing diy tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Can the [diy](/questions/tagged/diy) tag be removed?

I don't see how that would be a good tag for anyone to use.

Unless there is a [diy](/questions/tagged/diy) language / pattern / whetever I don't know about.

Comment: There are only 13 questions. Look through them, and remove it where it doesn't fit. I think many of these questions also look actually off-topic on Stack Overflow, so this is a good time to go around closing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was definitely a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) and is now removed.